# Acumular multples rows en 1

Tags: base-de-datos, oracle-11g

Como puedo generar algo como un array desde un select ? , no tenemos permitido crear procedimientos o funciones en la base de datos.

Expongo el problema.

```
$Query = "select to_char(ld.diario_id) diario_id,COLABORADOR_ID from XXQP.XXQP_DIARIO_LN_TBL ld inner join XXQP.XXQP_DIARIO_HD_TBL d on ld.diario_id=d.diario_id
WHERE 1 = 1 AND ld.ESTATUS=11 and ld.remesa_id is not null 
and d.fecha_cierre_diario >= to_date('2016-12-05 00:00:00','yyyy-mm-dd HH24:MI:SS') 
and d.fecha_cierre_diario <= to_date('2016-12-05 23:59:00','yyyy-mm-dd HH24:MI:SS')
and d.plaza_id = '37'
GROUP BY D.COLABORADOR_ID,ld.diario_id ORDER BY D.COLABORADOR_ID DESC;
```

Este query me arroja la informacion fila por fila.

```
DIARIO_ID   COLABORADOR_ID
27683       111250
28177       111250
28178       110493
28149       109260
27830       108978
27863       108978
27465       108698
27389       108698
```

Lo que estoy buscando es que me lo genere :

```
   DIARIO_ID    COLABORADOR_ID
   27683,28177  111250
   28178        110493
   28149        109260
   27830,27863  108978
   27465,27389  108698
```

De tal manera que yo envie algo similar a un "array" y procesarlo a su vez en un segundo query.

Quedo en espera de comentarios.

Por su atencion.

Gracias.

Comment: creo que te ayudaria un Group by en tu Colaborador_id

Comment: Hola @Rastalovely me puedes mostrar como ? Saludos.

Answer (score 1):

Leyendo la documentación y ejemplos encontre `LISTAGG`

```
select LISTAGG(diaro_id, ','),COLABORADOR_ID from XXQP.XXQP_DIARIO_LN_TBL ld inner join XXQP.XXQP_DIARIO_HD_TBL d on ld.diario_id=d.diario_id
WHERE 1 = 1 AND ld.ESTATUS=11 and ld.remesa_id is not null 
and d.fecha_cierre_diario >= to_date('2016-12-05 00:00:00','yyyy-mm-dd HH24:MI:SS') 
and d.fecha_cierre_diario <= to_date('2016-12-05 23:59:00','yyyy-mm-dd HH24:MI:SS')
and d.plaza_id = '37'
GROUP BY D.COLABORADOR_ID,ld.diario_id ORDER BY D.COLABORADOR_ID DESC
```

[Link ejemplos](https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/string-aggregation-techniques)

[Documentacion](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions089.htm#SQLRF30030)

Comment: antes existe un group by....

Comment: @Rastalovely actualice!

Comment: Genial, no conocia Listagg, pense que la solución estaba por parte de su html de @Jairo

Comment: No era mala opción hacerlo desde el html! Ambas me parecen validas!

Answer (score 0):

He encontrado la solucion, he quitado una tabla que no era del todo util y mi query quedo de la siguiente manera :

```
SELECT LISTAGG(DIARIO_ID,',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY DIARIO_ID DESC) "DIARIO_ID"
FROM XXQP.XXQP_DIARIO_HD_TBL
WHERE  fecha_cierre_diario >= to_date('2016-12-05 00:00:00','yyyy-mm-dd HH24:MI:SS') 
and fecha_cierre_diario <= to_date('2016-12-05 23:59:00','yyyy-mm-dd HH24:MI:SS')
and plaza_id = '37'
GROUP BY COLABORADOR_ID;
```

Agradezco a todos por su apoyo.

Sin ustedes no hubiese sido posible.

Saludos.